# Can Azure B2C signup check for existing dynamics crm contacts based on custom attributes

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement Azure B2C sign up and sign in process for D365 powerapps portal , since being new to whole Azure B2c, is there a way to check if the user Signing up with Azure B2C exists in dynamics crm with some configured attributes , then link the existing contact to New B2c users else create new in both B2C and dynamics crm

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

> **> To check if the user Signing up with Azure B2C exists in dynamics crm with some configured attributes**

As per **[Official Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/configure/configure-azure-ad-b2c-provider)** using identity provider you can able to preview user signing up Azure B2C exists in dynamics 365

- Before using power apps portal ***make sure you need to configure an authentication provider*** in addition if you have already some local account un power app portal

***In power apps portal ->apps->setting ->authentication setting -> azure ad B2C -> configure***

[image]

Once you completed configure identity Provider you can check the user Signing up with Azure B2C in dynamics ***if already exist***

> **To link the existing contact to New B2c users else create new in both B2C and dynamics crm**

While implementing Azure B2C sign up and sign in process for D365 PowerApps portal. In ***CRM –> Portals –> Site settings***

[image]

In this step when you configure identity provider user signs up to the portal using their email a contact record in Dynamics is created. ***when a person registers on the portal using their same email, Next time if there is another user sign-in with the same email, automatically new user should be connected to the existing contact***

[image]

Reference:
[To implement Azure B2C sign up and sign in process for D365 powerapps portal](https://debajmecrm.com/deep-dive-dynamics-365-portal-authentication-with-azure-ad-b2c-provider/) ***By Debajit Dutta***

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation that really helps , but is there a way to have any other attribute as unique identifier in B2c and D365 mapping instead of emailaddress

Comment: You can make changes under properties ![like](https://i.imgur.com/7NkX3CJ.png)